# chromedriver で headless と user-data-dir のオプションを同時に指定するとエラーが発生する

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, chromedriver

下記のコードを実行するとエラーが発生します。

それぞれのオプションを個別に指定するとエラーになりません。
`headless` と `user-data-dir` は同時に指定できないのでしょうか。

**実行したコード:**

```
var driverDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--headless");
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=userdata");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverDirectory, options);
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:63525/session timed out after 60 seconds.
Source=WebDriver
スタック トレース:
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
```

**開発環境:**
ChromeDriver 2.45.615291
.NET Core 2.2 コンソールアプリケーション

Comment: `user-data-dir`は`--user-data-dir`の間違いではないでしょうか。

Comment: `user-data-dir=userdata` の指定で動作確認できています。（Debug\netcoreapp2.2\userdata フォルダにプロファイル情報が保存され、実行時に前回実行時のログイン状態などが復元される）

Answer (score 0):

**全面改訂**

Seleniumの版数が上がった(4.x系になった)せいなのか、両方指定してもOKになっていました。
ただし、(Windowsでは？)ディレクトリの指定は絶対パスにしなければならないようです。

こちらの記事を参考に、TargetFrameworkをnet6.0でコンソールアプリを作成してみました。
[【C#】Seleniumを使ってChromeを自動操作してみる](https://www.hanachiru-blog.com/entry/2020/03/12/120000)
上記のmain関数内を以下のように書き変えてビルドし確認しています。
ディレクトリはあらかじめ作成しています。

```
string DriverPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Develop\\ChromeUserData");

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(DriverPath, chromeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://www.google.co.jp/");// URLに移動します。

Console.ReadKey();// なにかコンソールに文字を入力したらクロームを閉じる
driver.Quit();
```

---

なお、`chromeOptions.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Develop\\ChromeUserData");`の部分を`chromeOptions.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=ChromeUserData");`という風に相対パス指定すると、ディレクトリやいくつかのファイルは出来るのですが、以下のようなエラーになります。
つまり相対パス指定だと`C:\Program Files (x86)`の`Chrome`のインストール先にディレクトリやファイルを作ろうとしてエラーになっているようです。
ただし指定した`ChromeUserData`ディレクトリは、ビルドして動作させているアプリケーションの.exeのあるディレクトリにも作られているのが不思議ですが。

```
Starting ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51 (d537ec02474b5afe23684e7963d538896c63ac77-refs/branch-heads/4844@{#875}) on port 65379
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65382/devtools/browser/bccc2591-2ceb-4f7f-9b1a-9307e9796b8e
[0322/100832.023:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(291)] Error writing DevTools active port to file
[0322/100832.025:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(80)] Failed to create directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\js
[0322/100832.025:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(80)] Failed to create directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\wasm
[0322/100832.027:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(80)] Failed to create directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\js
[0322/100832.027:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(80)] Failed to create directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\wasm
[0322/100832.027:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(735)] Simple Cache Backend: wrong file structure on disk: 1 path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\js
[0322/100832.027:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(735)] Simple Cache Backend: wrong file structure on disk: 1 path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\wasm
[0322/100832.028:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(80)] Failed to create directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\js
[0322/100832.029:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(80)] Failed to create directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\wasm
[0322/100832.030:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(185)] Unable to create cache
[0322/100832.030:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(80)] Failed to create directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\js
[0322/100832.030:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(80)] Failed to create directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\wasm
[0322/100832.031:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(612)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[0322/100832.031:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(735)] Simple Cache Backend: wrong file structure on disk: 1 path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\js
[0322/100832.032:ERROR:simple_backend_impl.cc(735)] Simple Cache Backend: wrong file structure on disk: 1 path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\99.0.4844.74\ChromeUserData\Default\Code Cache\wasm
[0322/100832.032:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(185)] Unable to create cache
[0322/100832.033:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(185)] Unable to create cache
Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:65379/session timed out after 60 seconds.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
 ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: スレッドの終了またはアプリケーションの要求によって、I/O 処理は中止されました。.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): スレッドの終了またはアプリケーションの要求によって、I/O 処理は中止されました。
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)
   at SeleniumTest.MainClass.Main(String[] args) in C:\Develop\CSharpSelenium\CSharpSelenium\Program.cs:line 34
```

Comment: profile の変更については `user-data-dir=userdata` の指定で動作確認できています。（Debug\netcoreapp2.2\userdata フォルダにプロファイル情報が保存され、実行時に前回実行時のログイン状態などが復元される）